# How to "flag" product that had already been purchased before "flaging feature" was added?

Tags: 7, commerce, flags

In reference to this question and answer: [How to mark product if it has already been purchased by current user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240173/how-to-mark-product-if-it-has-already-been-purchased-by-current-user)

Now that I know how to "flag" the items in a way that lets me notify customer to avoid situation where customer buys two of the same product, remains one more question: 
How can I now mark or "flag" all the products, that had already been purchased before the flaging feature was added to the shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can think of a way to create a view which contains 1 row for each product and the user who actually bought such product, and which wasn't flagged with this "already purchased" flag, then you can use such view as part of an actual solution for your question. In that case, you could get this to work by using the integration of VBO with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, as further detailed below.

## Step 1: Create a Rules Component

Create a (rather basic) Rules component to flag a product by a user. Here is a variation of such component in Rules Export format (which processes nodes instead of products):

```
{ "rules_flag_node_by_a_user" : {
    "LABEL" : "Flag node by a user",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "flag", "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "flagging_user" : { "label" : "Flagging user", "type" : "user" },
      "flagged_node" : { "label" : "Node to be flagged", "type" : "node" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_flagnode" : {
          "flag" : "your_flag",
          "node" : [ "flagged-node" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "flagging_user" ],
          "permission_check" : "1"
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Node flagged for user  [flagging-user:name] (uid=[flagging-user:uid])" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This Rules Component uses a flag with machine name `your_flag`. After you edit that machine name to fit the name of your flag, you should be able to import this rule in your own site (using the Rules UI, which needs to be enabled). You can then adapt (or clone) it to make it work for your products instead of for nodes.

BTW: the Rules Action to display a message is just to see it at work while QA-testing this rule, feel free to remove that if you want.

## Step 2: Let VBO do the work

This step is pretty easy ... Just build an appropriate view (of all products that still need to be flagged) and transform it in a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) view. The clue to what you want VBO to do as an operation is ... **Execute the Rules Component from Step 1**. Be aware: when creating that VBO view, you really need
to create a view to "List Commerce Products".

If your Rules Component (= variation of the one in Step 1, where you flag products instead of nodes) cannot be selected as the VBO-action to be performed, then it might be because you need to change the order of the parameters used by the Rules Component: make the `flagged_node` (or `flagged_product` in your case) the very first parameter. This might be needed because it's a Rules Component with several parameters, and only the first one will be auto-populated by VBO. That might help to be able to select that Rules Component as your VBO action.

If you're not familiar with how to use VBO, have a look at the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo)". If you want even more, then also watch the subsequent "[Using Rules components with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter)" video.

**Attention**: to process like 100.000 records at once is quite a challenge (memory requirements, etc). Therefor you might want to also watch the video about "[More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings)" ... Before you are tempted to use VBO for processing them all at once ...

## Video tutorials

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).

Happy [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)-ing while [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)-ing!

Comment: Hi. This is a great answer. Weird thing is in tutorials field is called "Bulk Operations: Bulk". For me there is only "Bulk Operations: Commerce Product" and in the setting of that field there is no option to execute rules component I have just created. Editin rules component permission in rules did not have any effect on this.

Comment: @Nenotek hang on, your comment "rings a bell" over here ... Must be that something is not quite right in the view you're starting from (it'll only show Rules components the "make sense"). I need to do some minor digging / research to remember what exactly it was, I'll update you later on (possibly still today) about it ... PS: my sample component is to process (via VBO) "nodes", not "products", so make sure you somehow adapted that already for your usecase ...

Comment: I have changed the flagged_node data type to commerce product and other things too to reflect the fact that products are being flagged. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. But now component at least does exactly what is supposed to do.
I do think you are on the right track with the starting view having to be of certain type, since this indeed seems to limit what bulk operations are available. For example if I start with view of nodes, I get a lot more options, "Flag or unflag a node" for example.

Comment: I figured it out. And this has got to be the dumbest thing ever.. or at least one of them: In rules component I changed order of the "USES VARIABLES" part, so that "flagged_product" is declared before "flagging_user". After that I started to show up in the views, on VBO element "Bulk operations: Commerce Product". And you can only add that VBO element only if you create the view in "List Commerce Products" to begin with. How are you supposed to add correction or addition of this kind to answer of someone else?

Comment: Actually now that I look at the question and the answer, I'm starting to wonder if the component is sufficient enough. Since what I want is to flag all products for the users who have purchased that product, at some point in the past.

Comment: Now I'm thinking I need to actually list ORDERS, check them for status completed or invoiced, and then get line-items of those orders, and then flag commerce-products of those line items for the owner of that order. Should I make a new question about this if I can't solve this on my own or could this be considered to be the actual answer to original question?

Comment: @Nenotek I think that with my most recent edit I address the first 2 comments you added after my prior comment. Maybe that's sufficient to consider marking this answer as accepted? About your last comment: that sounds like a new (followup?) question to me.

Comment: This is now solved for me. Thank you very much for your help.
What I did was: 
1) Make rule Component "Check Order Data for Flagging" that Check Order entity for correct values (order state, owner, etc). Then it provides values (line-item and owner or the order) to another component (part 2).
2) Create component that does pretty much same as in your advice, but instead it flags the commerce-product for the user provided by the first component.
3) Ran the first component via VBO, trough view that lists orders with order status pending, processing, completed and invoiced.